# Constrain Button Programmatically To Bottom Center Of Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am building a tab bar with a prominent middle button for adding a post. The issue I'm running into is that my button fits well on iPhone 11 Pro Max but is not positioned correctly on other size iPhones (see images). [image]

[image]

I think the issue is that I'm setting the Y position absolutely instead of relative to the tabBar. I am confused on how to do this since I am adding the button programmatically instead of through the storyboard (where I know how to use relative constraints). Here is where I am setting the position:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: self.tabBar.center.x - 32, y: self.view.bounds.height - 115, width: 64, height: 64)
}
```

How can I set a relative position programmatically for my button so it is always half above and half below the tab bar, regardless of phone size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
let tabBarHeight = 64
let mainButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
mainButton.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: win.frame.size.height),size: CGSize(width: tabBarHeight, height: tabBarHeight))
mainButton.center = CGPoint(x: win.center.x, y: win.frame.size.height - tabBar.layer.bounds.height)
```

you set the size and set the center of the button to the center of the TabBar or move a little up like this code do.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another tabitem in the storyboard builder and then make:

```
tabbar.clipsToBounds = false
```

This is the best solution.

Comment: The big blue button is not being clipped. How does this help?